# Is there a way to detect mouseover, over specific words in RichTextLabel or any others text related nodes?

Tags: mouseover, godot, gdscript, richtext

I'm making a game on Godot in GDScript. I've got "abilities" in my game, a lot of them, really a lot of them. I might end up putting their description in XMLs or something else and even the rest of their info on it, and they might be "keywords" to simplify some explanations or recurrent mechanics.

So the question is: **Can you detect mouseover (or other mouse interactions too) over specifics texts/words in a `RichTextLabel`, maybe thanks to some BBCode?** Or maybe as said before there some text node more practical (even if I doubt it)?

From what I've seen, the RichTextLabel is the only to support text modifications and just "text difference" from the rest of the node, so might be the most able to, even if maybe very far, cuz of his ability to handle BBCode, but if what I'm thinking right now is the only solutions...

That would be to detect where certain BBCode balises in (X,Y) coordinates to place a "mouseover detect box" on those keywords, meaning you need to get (X,Y) coordinates of words in a paragraph, which isn't easily handled neither, you would need to calculate size of each character to calculate the position (X,Y) of a simple word... So yeah sound astoundingly hard to do.

Comment: There are far too many words in this post, and a lot of rambling and long, run-on sentences. Can you clean it up to **clearly and concisely** explain the problem that you're having?

Comment: Well sorry, isn't my strenght to be able to explain clearly things... I guess the more clearly and concise you can get is already in the title through.

Comment: If you can't explain the problem clearly and briefly, your question isn't suitable for this site. You should review [ask] for some suggestions as to how to better ask a question.

Comment: Since you accepted my answer, I have some confidence on my understanding of the question, and based on that I have edited it. However, it remains your question, and you can further edit it, or revert the changes I did. Making the questions more accesible might make them easier to answer, that is something to keep in mind for future questions. It might also help others with similar problems to find the solutions. Furthermore, you won't be attracting down votes, which you are free to not care about, yet I'll point out this site has privileges locked behind reputation (from up votes, et.al.).

Comment: Ah, one more thing: the question could also end up closed. Although I suppose that is not something to concern you right now. It is also worth keeping in mind for future questions.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, and to be honest I try my best (when I can) to explain the more concise way with the best explanation I can put, but I tend to do that for every problems/questions I post. Kinda annoying... I try to learn, but I can't just not post theses, even if they're poorly explained, or else I might just never ask any questions.
And since most of the search left me on post that are at least 2-3 years olds, so no up to date to last change of Godot...
+ I tend to mistake my inability to code correct code, to... bugs and feature missings...
Thanks for the info you twos.

Comment: But honestly each time I post I feel like I should'nt have just because that super messy and lots of others problems... Well that said, thanks. The question written better this way, trying to learn from it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RichTextLabel` is the easier approach here.

---

As you know, it works with BBCode. Now, there are to ways to populate it:

- You can set the `text` property with `bbcode_enabled` enabled and it will parse it. See [BBCode in RichTextLabel](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/ui/bbcode_in_richtextlabel.html).

  For example, this will be "hello" written in red:

  ```
  var label:RichTextLabel = $RichTextLabel

  label.text = "[color=red]hello[/color]"
  ```

  If you don't want to set it, but to append it, it is more efficient to use `append_text` (this way Godot does not have to parse the whole text, but only the new part):

  ```
  var label:RichTextLabel = $RichTextLabel

  label.append_text("[color=red]hello[/color]")
  ```
- Or you can do it by token...

  Setting the BBCode by tokens works like an stack machine. You push (open) tags, append text, and pop (close) tags.

  For example, this will be "hello" written in red:

  ```
  var label:RichTextLabel = $RichTextLabel

  label.push_color(Color.RED)
  label.add_text("hello")
  label.pop()
  ```

  **Note**: The `clear` method does nor clear the text, instead it pops (closes) all currently pushed (open) tags.

---

Now, there is a particular tag that will allow you to do what you want.

- If you are setting the `text` use `"[url=something]text[/url]"`.
- Otherwise, you want to use `push_meta("something")`.

This will *kind of* create an "hyperlink". More precisely, it makes an item indented to be interacted with, inside of which text will be formatted - by default - similar to an hyperlink in a browser.

*You, of course, are in control of the formatting. You might want to set `meta_underlined` to `false` to disable the default underline.*

What we are interested is the interactive part. While the tag does nothing by default, that is the point: we will define what it does. To do that, we need to handle some signals from the `RichTextLabel`:

- `meta_hover_started`: When the mouse pointer begins hovering over the contents of one of the "hyperlink"s.
- `meta_hover_ended`: When the mouse pointer stops hovering over the contents of one of the "hyperlink"s.
- `meta_clicked`: When the use clicks one of the "hyperlink"s.

And how do you know which "hyperlink"?

Well, these signals pass a value (`"something"` in the examples above), which comes from the tag:

- When you create the tag in text, you can set an "url" attribute, and the value you set there is what you will get from the signals.
- When you create it using `push_meta` you pass the value you want from the signals as an argument.

Here `push_meta` has an advantage over using text: the "url" attribute will only ever be an `String`, but the parameter of `push_meta` is a Variant, you can pass anything there, including a reference to an `Object`, or a `Dictionary` with multiple values.

The methods you connect to those signals would look something like this:

```
func _on_meta_clicked(meta):
    prints(meta)
```

Refer to [Using Signals](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html) to see how to make the connection.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I wasn't expecting that much of a clear answer, this is super hepful, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks you very much once again.